# Delay Evaluation of First Argument of ConditionalExpression until Second Argument Evaluated

Tags: performance-tuning, conditional

A particular set of equations I am solving,

```
sol = Solve[...]
```

yields a lengthy `List` of `ConditionalExpression`s, the arguments of which take a bit of time to evaluate

```
(sol /. x -> .22) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.26925, {...}} *)
```

which adds up when performed for hundreds of values of `x`.  This is so even though most instances of `ConditionalExpression` return `Undefined`, because both arguments of `ConditionalExpression` are evaluated, even when the second argument evaluates to `False`.  A work-around is

```
((sol /. ConditionalExpression[z1_, z2_] :>  ConditionalExpression[z1, z2 /. x -> .22])
    /. x -> .22) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0504917, {...}} *)
```

What alternatives are more compact or elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first solution is to use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
sol := ConditionalExpression[Pause[y], y > 2]
sol /. y -> 1 // RepeatedTiming
```

> {1.01, Undefined}

So it takes the whole second to evaluate even though the condition is false.

Now let's make a simple rule:

```
rule = ConditionalExpression[a_, b_] :> ConditionalExpression[Unevaluated[a], b];
```

and test it

```
sol /. rule /. y -> 1 // RepeatedTiming
```

> {7.*10^-6, Undefined}

```
sol /. rule /. y -> 2.1 // RepeatedTiming
```

> {2.101, Null}

So the first argument evaluates only when the condition is true.

The second (and slower) solution is to use [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html), which allows us to avoid using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
Refine[sol, y == 1] // Quiet // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00014, Undefined}

```
Refine[sol, y == 2.1] // Quiet // RepeatedTiming
```

> {2.1007, Null}

Note that [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) is needed to suppress FE complaints about conditions evaluating to false (which is expected).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps clearer is to just explicitly do the flow-control:

```
In[323]:= 
sol = Table[
   ConditionalExpression[
    Integrate[LegendreP[RandomInteger[100], t] x, {t, 0, \[Pi]}] + 
     RandomReal[], x > RandomReal[]], 10];

In[340]:= (sol /. ConditionalExpression[z1_, z2_] :>
    If[Unevaluated[z2] /. x -> .22,
     Unevaluated[z1] /. x -> .22,
     Undefined
     ]
  ) // AbsoluteTiming

Out[340]= {0.000078, {Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, 
  Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, 147944., Undefined, Undefined}}
```

or we can just delay evaluation of the first argument, but we still need 3 `ReplaceAlls`:

```
((sol /. ConditionalExpression[z1_, z2_] :> 
     ConditionalExpression[Unevaluated[z1 /. x -> .22], 
      z2 /. x -> .22])) // AbsoluteTiming

{0.000077, {Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, 
  Undefined, Undefined, 147944., Undefined, Undefined}}
```

I'm not sure we can avoid a three `ReplaceAll` based mechanism, honestly, without sacrificing some performance.