# Plot gives 1/0 on singularity of elementary function

Tags: plotting, bugs, singularity

My understanding is that Mathematica 11 `Plot` can now handle singularities automatically when plotting.  [identify-types-of-singularities-and-discontinuitie](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/visualization--labels-scales-exclusions/identify-types-of-singularities-and-discontinuitie.html)

I found an a function where Mathematica 11.0.1 gives a 1/0 error message. But still the plot is generated. Here it is `1/(Tan[1/t])`

```
f = 1/Tan[1/t];
Plot[f, {t, - Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[5]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is having hard time with `1/Tan[1/t]` The singularities for this function are (using function that finds these, thanks to Edmund and Carl Woll from [does-mathematica-have-a-function-to-find-all-singularities-of-an-expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135946/does-mathematica-have-a-function-to-find-all-singularities-of-an-expression))

```
singularityDomain[f_, x_] := Module[{res = FunctionDomain[f, x]}, 
  Reduce[! res] /; ! MatchQ[res, _FunctionDomain]]

Clear[x]
singularityDomain[1/Tan[1/x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this known, is this a bug?

Comment: Known bug. Comes from the improvements in the `Exclusions` system, i.e. setting `Exclusions -> None` turns off the messages (and the benefits of exclusion processing, too).

Comment: @rcollyer thanks. If this is known, should I delete this post then?

Comment: @rcollyer is there currently a question which has this bug in it?

Comment: @Nasser I think it's fine leaving it here.

Comment: @Feyre I don't know of another one. My knowledge comes from internal testing.

Comment: @rcollyer Then I suggest you post a formal answer so that it can be linked to.

Comment: @rcollyer Is this the same bug?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135952/error-powerinfy-infinite-expression-1-0-encountered-why-do-i-get-this

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think it is.

Comment: @MichaelE2 feel free to close it as duplicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug introduced in 11.0 with the improvements to the `Exclusions` code. One workaround is

```
Plot[1/Tan[1/t], {t, - Pi/2, Pi/2}, Exclusions -> None]
```

eliminates the message but removes the benefits of `Exclusions`. A better alternative is to specify the `Exclusions` yourself,

```
Plot[1/Tan[1/t], {t, - Pi/2, Pi/2}, Exclusions -> {Tan[1/t] == 0}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Recommend that you avoid any region where you know that a function becomes infinitely dense.

```
f[t_] = 1/Tan[1/t];

Manipulate[
 reg = ImplicitRegion[
   (ts && -max < t < -min) || min < t < max, t];
 Plot[f[t], t ∈ reg,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 15],
 {{ts, True, "two-sided"}, {True, False}},
 {{min, 0.025}, 0.001, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{max, Pi/2}, 1.1 min, Pi/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]